# how to create a decorator/ wrapper class in python to pass the attributes of error logs as a single parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wrapper, python-decorators

class Request(APIView):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def test_api_method(self):
    print('This is Test API')
    db_logger = logging.getLogger('db')


    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        db_logger.exception(e, extra={'user': self.user.username, 'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,'method_name': sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
                                      'module_name': __package__, 'ip_address': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())})

    return Response({'data': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to create a  decorator or a wrapper class to pass the parameters in the db_logger.exception() as a sin single parameter.
Mainly, I wanted to replace this dictionary---> extra={............}  with a single parameter so that this error logging method can be used to log errors across all classes and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example, on how you can create decorators, and access the wrapped function and its parameters.

```
from functools import wraps

def error_logger(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwd):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwd)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error in ', func.__name__)
            # reference self as: args[0]
    return wrapper

class my_class:
    @error_logger
    def my_function(self):
        return 1/0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class().my_function()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please explain a bit on how to pass the arguments through an example?

Comment: @AmarnathJ the wrapper will wrap around and invoke the original function. In python, functions can have unnamed, and named parameters. In most general, it is stated as: `*args, **kwd`, where you can refer unnamed arguments by their location, like: `args[0], args[1], ...`, or named arguments by their names, like: `kwd['name1'], kwd['name2'], ...`. In case of a class, the class-object is always accessed as the first unnamed parameter, i.e.: `args[0]`. In the code, you can access all arguments from wrapper, and it passes all arguments unchanged to the original function.